# Sending mail doesn't work from request, only from Main java

Tags: java, gmail

I have a problem sending mail in a Java application. If i'm trying to send an email from Main, it's working perfectly, but when I try to send one from a request, it gets stuck. I've already tried with SSL an TLS. 
        The code for my mail service where I also set smtp details and i'm setting to who, from who and what to send.

```
@Service
public class MailService {

    public static void sendMailSSL(){
        final String username = "x@gmail.com";
        final String password = "password";

        System.out.println("Sending mail...");
        Properties props = new Properties();

        props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(username,password);
                    }
                });

        try {

            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(username));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    InternetAddress.parse("plesha.gabi@gmail.com"));
            message.setSubject("Testing Subject");
            message.setText("Dear Mail Crawler," +
                    "\n\n No spam to my email, please!");

            Transport.send(message);

            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

And the class where i call this method: 

@CrossOrigin(maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {


    @Autowired
    private MailService mailService;



    @RequestMapping(value = "/sendmail", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public String sendMail() throws MessagingException  {
        MailService.sendMailSSL();
        return "Successfully send an e-mail";
    }
}
```

Comment: have you debug it? where the code stuck when you try to send one from request?

Comment: Here are some things to consider: `MailService` is annotated as a service, however `sendMailSSL()` is a static method. This means injecting `mailService` into your controller with @AutoWire is not having any effect; You're getting a `mailService` instance but you're not using it. This is not causing your issue, but it's related to something that likely is: You're using static methods on `Session` and `Transport` within `sendMailSSL()`. This means you have no control over the inputs to those method calls; Calling `sendMailSSL()` multiple times can yield different results because...

Comment: ... inputs are changing without your knowledge nor consent. You're getting a different outcome when you call `sendMailSSL()` from your `Main` class and when you call it from a controller request handler because `sendMailSSL()` doesn't allow you to control its inputs; It has no method arguments. If you address that you'll be able to pinpoint the root cause more readily.

Comment: What error message are you getting? Try to use `put("mail.debug", "true");` to see messages from javax.mail.* API.